# ACF Wordpress get posts by category and custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem with ACF in Wordpress. I created own field [image] And created own plugin to display it, but I don't know how I can display all my fields.
Now I have something like this:

```
   wp_reset_postdata();
   $myargs = array (
      'showposts' => 6
   );
   $myquery = new WP_Query($myargs);
     if($myquery->have_posts() ) :
       while($myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post();
   ?>
   <p>
     <?php the_title(); ?>
   </p>
   <?php endwhile;
         endif;
         wp_reset_postdata();
```

And this display me all posts. I want to display posts only from category "Raporty" and I want to display all of my custom fields.

Sorry for my english ;)

Comment: I ask because I want to be sure... Category "Raporty" - is it taxonomy or custom post type?

Answer (score 1):

Siema Kubol,

to show posts only with post_type 'raporty' add it to `$myargs`:

```
$myargs = array (
      'showposts' => 6,
      'post_type' => 'raporty'
   );
```

In wp loop you could just use e.g. `get_field( 'typ_raportu' )`. Outside loop `get_field( 'typ_raportu', post_id_here )`.